# Java: Inner class inside an inner class

Tags: java, class, syntax, declaration

Please excuse me if this question has been asked before.
I have searched around the web and here at stack **overflow**.

**Case:**

I am stuck at my java project and the compiler won't compile my project when I try to use
an inner class inside another.

**Code:**

```
public class outer  {
    public class middle {
        public class inner  {
            public int variable = "8";
        }
    }
}
```

**Declaration:**

I am trying to declare the classes like this:

```
outer outerObject = new outer();
outerObject.middle middleObject = outerObject.new middle();
outerObject.middleObject.inner innerObject = outerObject.middleObject.new inner();
```

**Compilation results:**

```
source\start.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                      outerObject.middleObject.inner innerObject = outerObject
.middleObject.new inner();
^
```

Any reply would be much appreciated! Wether my intentions are impossible or if I am simply doing something wrong.

**Have a nice day!**

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
outerObject.middleObject.inner innerObject = outerObject.middleObject.new inner();
```

should be

```
outer.middle.inner innerObject = middleObject.new inner();
```

`outerObject` does not have a `middleObject` field. Unfortunately Java allows statics to be qualified with variable expressions, so you get some strange code actually compiling.

This would probably be clearer if you stuck with the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you!
This solved my problem!
I think there should be a tutorial for this.
There may be some already, but I could not find any.

Comment: @OleKristianMøller-Hansen Specifying the outer `new` for an inner class is such an obscure and pointless feature, that I don't really think it's tutorial territory.

Comment: @OleKristianMøller-Hansen maybe mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your code will never compile as:

```
public int variable = "8";
```

This line should be

```
public int variable = 8;
```

First change this line.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public class outer  {
    public class middle {
        public class inner  {
            public int variable = 8;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        outer outerObject = new outer();
        middle middleObject = outerObject.new middle();
        middle.inner innerObject = middleObject.new inner();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
    Outer outerObject = new Outer();
    Outer.middle middleObject = outerObject.new middle();
    Outer.middle.inner innerObject = middleObject.new inner();
```

Also you need to change:

```
 public int variable = "8";
```

to

```
 public String variable = "8";
```